# Microsoft Office: What's New Icon in ImageMSO

Tags: c#, ms-office, office365, vsto, office-interop

I am not able to find the below icon in ImageMSO. I noticed that Microsoft have used the same icon in their Office applications. So I want to know whether it's part of ImageMSO.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is part of the Office Fluent UI Command Identifiers. The `imageMso` name you are looking for is "WhatsNewRecentUpdates" as in:

`<button id="rxbtnMyButton" label="Super Megaphone" imageMso="WhatsNewRecentUpdates" 
onAction="rxbtnMyButton_click" supertip="Generate a deafening sound." tag="boom" />`

You can find all of Microsoft's Office 2016 and Office 365 Fluent UI Command Identifiers in this GitHub repository:

[Office 365 Current Channel Fluent UI Command Identifiers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers)

**Edit 1/11/2019**

Updated the above link per Ben's comment.

Comment: The link is dead.